# How to use std::iter::Iterator::map for tree-like structures in Rust?

Tags: rust

As I understand the idiomatic way to apply a function to each element of a structure in Rust, is to implement `IntoIterator` and `FromIterator` and use `map` and `collect`. Like this:

```
enum F<A> {
    // fields omitted
}

impl<A> IntoIterator for F<A> {
    // implementation omitted
}

impl<A> FromIterator<A> for F<A> {
    // implementation omitted
}

fn mapF<A, B>(x : F<A>, f) -> F<B> 
    where f : Fn(A) -> B 
{
    x.into_iter().map(f).collect()
}
```

However it doesn't seem possible to implement `FromIterator` for a tree, because there are multiple ways to organize a sequence of values into a tree. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 4):

> the idiomatic way to apply a function to each element of a structure in Rust, is to implement `IntoIterator` and `FromIterator`

This is not quite true. The idiomatic way is to provide one iterator, but you don't have to implement these traits.

Take for example `&str`: there isn't a canonical way to iterate on a string. You could iterate on its bytes or its characters, therefore it doesn't implement `IntoIterator` but has two methods `bytes` and `chars` returning a different type of iterator.

A tree would be similar: there isn't a single way to iterate a tree, so it could have a `depth_first_search` method returning a `DepthFirstSearch` iterator and a `breadth_first_search` method returning a `BreadthFirstSearch` iterator.

Similarly a `String` can be constructed from an iterator of `&str` or and iterator of `char` so `String` implements both `FromIterator<&str>` and `FromIterator<char>`, but it does not implement `FromIterator<u8>` because random bytes are unlikely to form a valid UTF-8 string.

That is, there isn't always a one-to-one relation between a collection, and its iterator.

---

> and use […] `collect`

This is (mostly) incorrect. Collecting is not a good way to consume an iterator, *unless* you actually want to use the collected result afterwards. If you only want to execute the effect of an iterator, use `for` of the [`for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) method.

Answer (score 1):

You could include information about tree structure into the iterator, something like

```
impl F {
    pub fn path_iter(self) -> impl Iterator<Iter=(TreePath, A)> { ... }
    // rest of impl
}

impl<A> FromIterator<(TreePath, A)> for F<A> {
    // implementation omitted
}

fn mapF<A, B>(x : F<A>, f) -> F<B> 
    where f : Fn(A) -> B 
{
    x.path_iter().map(|pair| (pair.0, f(pair.1))).collect()
}
```

With `TreePath` a type specific for your tree. Probably better representing not the path itself but how to move to the next node.

I originally suggested implementing `IntoIterator` with `Item = (TreePath, A)` but on further thought the default iterator should still have `Item = A`.